# Mapping Alamofire Response Dictionary to Class with a generic class

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, objectmapper

I have a generic class with a function to fetch a json response from remote url using `Alamofire` and serialize using `AlamofireObjectMapper` library.
The code of the function is:

```
    class func getDataFromNetwork<T: Mappable>(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (T?, NSError) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(urlString).responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<T, NSError>) in
        guard response.result.isSuccess else {
            print("Error while Fetching: \(response.result.error)")
            completion(nil, response.result.error)
            return
        }
        if let responseObject = response.result.value {
            print(responseObject)
            completion(responseObject, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in the implementation part, I have used following code:

```
    Fetcher.getDataFromNetwork(urlString: "https://my.json.url") { NHRootClass?, error in

}
```

Fetcher is the class that contains `getDataFromNetwork()` and NHRootClass is the class `Mappable`. I am unable to write the implementation part to get the response from my `Generic Function`.

And here's the class `NHRootClass`.

```
public final class NHRootClass: Mappable, NSCoding {

  // MARK: Declaration for string constants to be used to decode and also serialize.
private struct SerializationKeys {
static let countTotal = "count_total"
static let status = "status"
static let posts = "posts"
static let pages = "pages"
static let count = "count"
}

  // MARK: Properties
public var countTotal: Int?
public var status: String?
public var posts: [NHPosts]?
public var pages: Int?
public var count: Int?

// MARK: ObjectMapper Initializers
/// Map a JSON object to this class using ObjectMapper.
///
/// - parameter map: A mapping from ObjectMapper.
public required init?(map: Map){

}

/// Map a JSON object to this class using ObjectMapper.
///
/// - parameter map: A mapping from ObjectMapper.
public func mapping(map: Map) {
  countTotal <- map[SerializationKeys.countTotal]
  status <- map[SerializationKeys.status]
  posts <- map[SerializationKeys.posts]
  pages <- map[SerializationKeys.pages]
  count <- map[SerializationKeys.count]
}

/// Generates description of the object in the form of a NSDictionary.
///
/// - returns: A Key value pair containing all valid values in the object.
public func dictionaryRepresentation() -> [String: Any] {
  var dictionary: [String: Any] = [:]
  if let value = countTotal { dictionary[SerializationKeys.countTotal] = value }
  if let value = status { dictionary[SerializationKeys.status] = value }
  if let value = posts { dictionary[SerializationKeys.posts] = value.map { $0.dictionaryRepresentation() } }
  if let value = pages { dictionary[SerializationKeys.pages] = value }
  if let value = count { dictionary[SerializationKeys.count] = value }
  return dictionary
}

// MARK: NSCoding Protocol
required public init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  self.countTotal = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: SerializationKeys.countTotal) as? Int
  self.status = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: SerializationKeys.status) as? String
  self.posts = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: SerializationKeys.posts) as? [NHPosts]
  self.pages = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: SerializationKeys.pages) as? Int
  self.count = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: SerializationKeys.count) as? Int
}

public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
aCoder.encode(countTotal, forKey: SerializationKeys.countTotal)
aCoder.encode(status, forKey: SerializationKeys.status)
aCoder.encode(posts, forKey: SerializationKeys.posts)
aCoder.encode(pages, forKey: SerializationKeys.pages)
aCoder.encode(count, forKey: SerializationKeys.count)
}

}
```

Comment: Can you pls post the code of `NHRootClass`?

Comment: I have updated it, please have a look now!

Comment: Is your issue resolved? I am facing a similar issue.